# Solve for number of elements when total is given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm writing a program and I came up with a formula to calculate the total. Now I'm trying to figure out the total number of elements that I can have. 250 represents the width of each element and 20 is the spacing between elements. There is no spacing from the left of the first element and there is no spacing from the right of the last element. For this reason I have (numberOfElements - 1) * 20 in the formula.

Now the math is correct to get the total needed, however I can't figure out how to reverse engineer it to calculate number of elements if I know the total. Its ok if the answer ends up being 5.11254, because I can grammatically round down.

$$ Total = (250 * N) + ((N - 1) * 20);$$

Example:

$$ 250 = (250 * 1) + ((1 - 1) * 20)$$
$$ 520 = (250 * 2) + ((2 - 1) * 20)$$
$$ 790 = (250 * 3) + ((3 - 1) * 20)$$

What I'm asking here is not a coding question, but a math question. What would be the formula to calculate number of elements $N$?

Lastly, I wasn't sure what tags to association with this question, if you think I should change them to something else, please let me know.

Comment: $T = 250n + (n-1)20$, solve for n, $n= (T+20)/270$. İntuitively, for each element you need a space of $270$, except the last one. Hence add $20$ to total and divide by $270$

Comment: @Atbey 1 Element has 0 space. 2 elements have 20 space. 3 Elements have 40. 4 Elements have 60. Etc... This is why I can't figure this out. Its not that every element has space of 20.

Comment: 1 element is 250 units long.  If you have (250 + 20)/270 = 1.  2 elements are 500 + 1 space = 520.  (520 + 20)/270 = 2.  Suppose you have x units and the are 250x + (x-1) spaces is 250x + (x-1)20= w.  Well, Atbey is claiming that (w + 20)270 = x.  And s/he is right.  Notice 250x + (x-1)20 = 270x - 20=w.  So (w+20)/270 = (270x - 20 + 20)/270 = (270x)/270 = x.

Comment: @fleablood I don't think I explained my problem well so I updated with some examples. What you are suggesting I don't think can work.

Comment: Of course it can.  It fits every single one of your examples.  The only case it doesn't fit is $w=0;n = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is the number of elements, and $w$ is the available width, your equation is $$w=250n+20(n-1)\implies w+20=270n\implies \boxed{n=\frac{w+20}{270}}$$

Comment: I have updated my question with better examples. Your formula doesn't cover the first scenario, but seems to work for the others.

Comment: Of course this answer covers the first scenario.  If $w = 250$ then $n = \frac {w+20}{270} = \frac {250 + 20}{270} = \frac {270}{270} = 1$.

Comment: I was using my code to very the answer, and it seems there a bug where it is behaving differently for first scenario for some reason. Yeah I think this is correct now that I'm using a calculator. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NickD Thank you.